# How to read data from firebase realtime database into a class type in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

This is the json structure of the real-time database in the Firebase.
"cars" is under root

```
{
  "Cars" : {
    "A1" : "0",
    "A2" : "0",
    "B1" : "0",
    "B2" : "1",
    "C1" : "0",
    "C2" : "0",
    "D1" : "0",
    "D2" : "0"
  },
  "users":{
     "-MZRTeYBDESkh2nTdPOZ" : {
         "carlocatiton" : "A1",
         "carnum" : "dd",
         "username" : "dd"
     }
  }
}
```

I want to read from A1 to D2 below Cars.
Data can be added from the app to Firebase.

I tried.

**SaveCarInfo.java**

```
public class SaveCarInfo {
    public String A1;
    public String A2;
    public String B1;
    public String B2;
    public String C1;
    public String C2;
    public String D1;
    public String D2;

    public SaveCarInfo(){    }
    public SaveCarInfo(String A1, String A2,String B1,String B2,String C1,String C2,String D1,String D2){
        this.A1 = A1;
        this.A2 = A2;

        this.B1 = B1;
        this.B2 = B2;

        this.C1 = C1;
        this.C2 = C2;

        this.D1 = D1;
        this.D2 = D2;
}
```

}

**MainActivity.java**

```
public void load() {
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference carRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Cars");
    carRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            SaveCarInfo saveCarInfo = snapshot.getValue(SaveCarInfo.class);
            saveA1Status = saveCarInfo.A1; //saveA1Status is declared above

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            // Getting Post failed, log a message
            Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", error.toException());
        }
    });
}
```

I tried, but I couldn't get the value in the database as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

When mapping between fields in the class and properties in the database, Firebase uses Java Bean naming conventions. In this convention your field `public String A1` actually refers to a property `a1` with a lowercase `a`.

To match the JSON, you can use the [`PropertyName` annotation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/PropertyName) on the fields:

```
public class SaveCarInfo {
    @PropertyName("A1")
    public String A1;
    @PropertyName("A2")
    public String A2;
    @PropertyName("B1")
    public String B1;
    @PropertyName("B2")
    public String B2;
    ... etc
```